# Pop last key from URL

Tags: category, url, magento-1.9.2.1

i'd like to know, how i can remove the most recent category from the URL.
The structure looks for example like following: "/parentCategory/subCategory/"

Now, after pressing a button i want to get back to the "parentCategory" and therefore removing the "subCategory" from the URL.
Does magento provide something out of the box?

Comment: Are you want functionality same as breadcrumbs ?? If yes then you can get help from hare. http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-easily-add-breadcrumbs-to-any-page/

Comment: Hm. I want to have the back-link (which is the same as in the breadcrumbs), but i want to have it in a filter (layer navigation filter).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<?php
    $string = '/parentCategory/subCategory/';
    $data = explode('/',$string);    
    $data2  = array_filter($data );
    array_pop($data2);
    $FinalUrl = implode('/',$data2);
    print_r($FinalUrl);   
    //output = parentCategory

    ?>
```

Comment: Isn't there a function for magento doing this?